# Return an observable collection from an entity collection

Tags: c#

I have the following collection and I would like to return

```
ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
foreach (var p in context.Persons.ToList())
{
    people.add((Person)p);
}
```

How can I do it without having to loop through the collection?

Answer (score 4):

Use ObservableCollection constructor that has list as a parameter:

```
ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>(context.Persons.ToList());
```

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the ObservableCollection class that
>   contains elements copied from the specified list.

Answer (score 1):

Initialise your ObservableCollection with a List

```
people = new ObservableCollection<Person>(context.Persons);
```